# Where can I buy historic raw order by order data for Euronext market?

Tags: data, market-data, european

I cannot find any vendor that sell the full depth order by order data historically.
I called Euronext and for some sick reason they "have the data" but "do not sell it". Do you guys know where I can buy it ?

Answer (score 4):

For NYSE EuroNext data I think [this](http://www.nyxdata.com/Data-Products/Euronext-Cash-Full-Order-Book-FOB) is the page to start at.

This seems to be what you are after [here](http://www.nyxdata.com/nysedata/default.aspx?tabID=1098)

There are sample files provided [here](ftp://ftp.nyxdata.com/Historical%20Data%20Samples/) showing hte format of their many historical data sets.

Comment: I will call them back and keep u posted, brilliant answer thank you

Comment: They are NOT selling the data anymore... just unbelievable... any other idea ?